# How can I download a Flash video from a website?

Tags: video, download, flash

I am trying to download a Flash video, so I can try to convert it to a normal DVD.

([FYI: this is a religious video](http://www.lds.org/pa/rs/home/rsvideo.html?xml=rsvideo_8911.xml).)

Is it possible to download this video?  If so, how could I do this?

Comment: Does it change anything that it's a religious video?

Comment: @Camilo Martin - It was just fair warning so that people don't think I am trying to do covert preaching on Super User.

Comment: Also, its useful to know he's not trying to download YouTube vidoes with songs and then extract the audio track, as that would be unauthorized procurement of the song.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have Firefox, install the [Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006) extension.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: If you have firefox, it temporary saves flash videos in temporary directory :-)

Comment: I don't normally use Firefox but I'll happily use it just for downloading Flash videos thanks to this awesome extension.

Answer (score 1):

In [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) it's a bit convoluted, but if you

1. start 'loading' or playing the flash video, then
2. from the Window menu select Activity

you'll see something loading with the extension flv or swf.  (In the case of the linked video above, it's actually an MP4 file, which may or may not be because I use clickToflash on my Mac.)

3. Hold down option and double-click the flv or whatever file as it's loading, and you should see the download begin.

*[Easily download YouTube movies via Safari Web Browsers](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070420014456930)* has a (possibly clearer) explanation, along with a bunch more application recommendations that can automate this process for you, including a bookmarklet:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way by which you can download any flash video from any website:

1. Go to http://file2hd.com
2. Enter the page-url
3. Check "I have read and agree to the Terms of Service."
4. Select Object
5. Right click on the file with extension .swf and save it!

Answer (score -1):

I usually use Keepvid to download videos from web, the procedure is quite simple:

1. Copy the URL of video from YouTube or other sites and then navigate to Keepvid.com.
2. Paste the URL into download field and then click "Download".
3. Wait for the app detects the source of video and it will expand a list of several media formats for you to choose.
4. Select a media format you prefer and click on the "Download" icon along with it, and then you just need to wait for a short while till the download completes.
5. Once done, you will get the flash video in chosen format in download directory of your browser.

Keepvid currently supports up to 30 sites as described on its official site, if you're looking for alternative video downloader with more functions, you may also check [sites like Keepvid](http://acethinker.com/online-downloader/sites-like-keepvid.html).